# How do you track overall heroku postgres database contention

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

A few bullets to get us started

- Query Throughput (will the overall number of queries melt my db) is a resource that is (while partially related) different from query latency (does this one singular query take too long for the user experience)
- The performance resources for Heroku appear to only help diagnose and manage queries that have a long execution time
- You can't assume that load is uniform or that the database is the only component that can limit on horizontal scaling e.g. external services or redis
- Knowing your current and aggregate database cpu usage is useful for determining at what level of load the database will become the bottleneck

How do you figure out if your database is already at the maximum amount of load and thus horizontal scaling will not be effective?

For any system in which I had control of the database I would be tracking stats on the database server cpu (if db is at or near 100%, probably not gonna get any more throughput). New Relic in specific does not have any stats on database cpu usage.